# Deploy Angular universal app to non root path in firebase hosting

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

i have multiple angular apps for different paths

here is my `firebase.json`

```
...
"hosting": {
            "target": "app",
            "public": "dist",
            "ignore": [
                "firebase.json",
                "**/.*",
                "**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "/app2/**",
                    "function": "serveApp2Ssr"
                },
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "function": "serverAppSsr"
                }
            ]
        }
 ...
```

i have two functions `serverAppSsr` for serving first ssr app and `serveApp2Ssr` for serving app2

i build my `app2` with the command `ng build app2 --base-href /app2/ --deploy-url /about/`

both apps work well locally

but when the deploy `serveApp2Ssr` and run the app with the domain url [https://domain.url/app2] it says `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app2 or whatever path i visit`

the error occurs in angular routing module.

what i understand is when firebase function `serveApp2Ssr` trys to resolve the angular app with 'app2' as suffix which is unknown to angular app routing module

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @code show me your server.ts file. i dont remember what i actully did but i think i can help you. just show me your server.ts file

Comment: My use case is different, it is a single page app.  Angular  no server.ts

Comment: @code how can you have angular universal without a server.ts ?

Comment: It is a regular Angular app not universal.

Comment: @code you have a totally different case. cant say without looking at the details. what you are trying to achieve. your fireabse.json and how does your build directory looks ?